# query to find out the matched records of two tables with the same column names

Tags: mysql

See these two sample tables:

**Table 1:**

```
id   volume  price  total

1       A      B     C

2       D      E     F

3       G      H     I
```

**Table 2:**

```
id   volume  price  total

1       A      B     C

2       G      H     I

3       D      E     F
```

I want the output which are equal from table1 and table2. I have tried many ways but no results.

output should be like this:

```
id volume price total

1      G    H     I

2      D     E     F
```

Comment: why not A B C ?  (seems equals to mee)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT with inner join should work.

```
SELECT 
    table1.id, 
    table1.volume, 
    table1.price,
    table1.total 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.volume = table2.volume 
    AND table1.price = table2.price 
    AND table1.totak = table2.price.
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN table 2 AS T2 WHERE T1.volume=T2.volume AND T1.price=T2.price AND T1.total=T2.total`